# Optimising a force directed graph

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, graph

I have written a force directed graphing implementation based on the EpForceDirectedGraph.cs graph in C# for Unity but it can only handle upto 1000 nodes, below what I need of around 4000 nodes. I have looked at the code for days but can't seem to see anyways to speed it up! Have a look, any help would be appreciated! I have these functions running 85 times on 400 nodes to generate a correct graph which means the apply force function is running 27,000,000 times during start!

Please note I am using WebGL as my build target so Multi-Threading and SIMD might not help, I am open to suggestions with these tools however.

These are the main application functions:

```
    * @Description     applied coulombs law to determine the push force between 2 points as well as*
    *                  the attraction to center and updating of the velocity and acceleration      *
    *                                                                                              *
    * @parameters      iTimeStep - the time since last frame                                       *
    ************************************************************************************************/
    protected override void applyNodeLaws(float iTimeStep)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < graph.nodes.Count; i++)
        {
            //applies coulomb's law to each node 
            Point3D point1 = GetPoint(graph.nodes[i]);
            for (int j = 0; j < graph.nodes.Count; j++)
            {
                Point3D point2 = GetPoint(graph.nodes[j]);
                if (point1 != point2)
                {
                    Vector3 d = point1.position - point2.position;
                    float distance = d.magnitude + 0.1f;
                    Vector3 direction = d.normalized;

                    point1.ApplyForce((direction * Repulsion) / (distance * 0.5f));
                    point2.ApplyForce((direction * Repulsion) / (distance * -0.5f));

                }
            }
            //Applies centre attraction
            Vector3 centreDirection = point1.position * -1.0f;
            float displacement = centreDirection.magnitude;
            centreDirection = centreDirection.normalized;
            point1.ApplyForce(centreDirection * (Stiffness * displacement * 0.4f));

            //converts acceleration to velocity
            point1.velocity += (point1.acceleration * iTimeStep);
            point1.velocity *= Damping;
            point1.acceleration = Vector3.zero;
            //applies velocity to position
            point1.position += (point1.velocity * iTimeStep);


        }
    }

   /************************************************************************************************
    * @Description     applied hookes law to determine the spring force between 2 points           *
    ************************************************************************************************/
    protected override void applyHookesLaw()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < graph.edges.Count; i++)
        {
            Spring3D spring = GetSpring(graph.edges[i]);
            Vector3 d = spring.point2.position - spring.point1.position;
            float displacement = spring.Length - d.magnitude;
            Vector3 direction = d.normalized;

            spring.point1.ApplyForce(direction * (spring.K * displacement * -0.5f));
            spring.point2.ApplyForce(direction * (spring.K * displacement * 0.5f));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should look into GPGPU https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2014/02/01/n-body-galaxy-simulation-using-compute-shaders-on-gpgpu-via-unity-3d/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply, the link to the project on your website is down, could I get a copy to mess around with?

Comment: Sadly no, it's for an older version of Unity and annoyingly Unity has the habit of making breaking changes with new versions.  Anyway, the important code is there on my blog. I hope you can make sense of it

Comment: Thanks anyway, I'll take a look, do you know if this would be an appropriate solution for a WebGL based build? If not, I was thinking about offloading the processing to a Heroku based server and returning the data

Comment: I know web-based apps can use OpenGL but I'm not sure if it supports GPGPU

Comment: I put together a project with compute shaders and It didn't work on my pc (using Unity 5.5 which doesn't have support for this on Mac OS) or on WebGL when built. Getting a can't find kernel error, guessing that means it won't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, we decided to offload all processing to an external AWS based Heroku server. With a callout timeout of 40 seconds, we can complete millions of calculations which would normally take upto 30 mins to generate!

We also implemented an Octree based node system which enabled us to run it live!